# Visual Studio settings doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, settings

I have a simple `WPF` application which allows user to manage their workers. User can add, remove and edit workers. I would like to remember users and their workers after restarting the application, so I think I need to use `Visual Studio` settings (I mean `Settings.settings` file and `Settings` class). 
My application displays login window, user write login and password and the main window displays allowing to see and mainpulate user's workers.
When user logs in I would like to load his list of workers and after he logs out I would like to save modified list. 
I created a setting called `AllUsers` of type `UserCollection`. Here is the code of this simple class and the `User` class:

```
public class UserCollection
{
    public UserCollection(IEnumerable<User> users = null)
    {
        Users=new List<User>(users ?? new List<User>());
    }
    public List<User> Users;
}

public class User
{
    public string Login { get; }
    public string Password { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers { get; set; } 

    public User(string login, string password)
    {
        Login = login;
        Password = password;
        Workers=new ObservableCollection<Worker>();
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a class `PropertiesManager` which would manage settings, update and saves them. Here is the code:

```
public static class PropertiesManager
{
    public static List<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            if (Settings.Default.AllUsers == null)
            {
                Settings.Default.AllUsers=new UserCollection();
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            return Settings.Default.AllUsers.Users;
        }
        set
        {
            Settings.Default.AllUsers.Users = value;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    } 
    public static User VerifyUser(string login, string password)
    {
        User current = Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login.Equals(login));
        if (current == null)
        {
            current=new User(login,password);
            Users.Add(current);
            SaveUser();
        }
        return current;
    }

    public static void SaveUser()
    {
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

I also think that `Settings.settings` file may be useful:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01  /settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="HRManger.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
<Profiles />
<Settings>
    <Setting Name="AllUsers" Type="HRManger.UserCollection" Scope="User">
        <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
</Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

I noticed that when I log in as user1 add some workers and log out, then do the same as user2 and again log in as user1, his workers displays properly. However, I'll lose everything when I restart the application.
I do not know what I did wrong. Have I forgotten about something important?

Comment: Oh, I know I can save generic type `List<Users>` in settings when I write `<Setting Name="AllUsers" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;HRManager.Model.User&gt;" Scope="User">` but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason why settings wasn't saved and restored properly, so I post that answer. To understand why that happens why must realize how `Visual Studio settings` works. It is known that it is a quite common `XML serialization` so it has a few requirements.

Only non-static and non-readonly fields and properties are serialized and we have to have non-parameterised default constructor in the class to ensure that this class can be serialized as `XML`. So, in this question we want to serialize the collection of `User` objects, so the generic type (in this case `User`) has to have a non-parameterised constructor. That's the main reason why that does not work.